# Drupal Webform textfield dynamic growing list

Tags: drupal, dynamic

Just curious...

I have a project where people can input their cooking recipes. I would like to build a webform  that will have a textfield and when it is filled in a new textfield appears below. A "growing textfield list". Let me try to show it here:

```
Ingredient #1  _________________________________  [add]
```

When you type and ingredient click "add" you then are going to see:

```
Ingredient #1  Potatoes_________________________
Ingredient #2  _________________________________  [add]
```

Sorry for not knowing the proper markup. However if anyone knows:

a) the proper term for this ( I call a growing textfield list )?
b) how to do it with webform in drupal?

Comment: Why not using taxonomy auto-complete with multiple selection?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of doing this without any programming:

- If you are using the Webform module (not sure if by webform you mean the node form or the Webform module) then you can try the [Webform Add More](http://drupal.org/project/webform_addmore) module which enables what you want. The only downside is that it works only with fieldsets so you'll have to put your textfield in a fieldset and enable the add more functionality on that fieldset.
- If you are using CCK then it's really simple: just add a new textform field and set it's number of values to be "Unlimited". However I would use something like [Hierarchical Select](http://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select/) which would allow users to reuse ingredients, add new ones and it would also allow you to categorize them.